# How to make custom sieve/filter for Imagus hover zoom extension?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

**TLDR :** Can anyone guide on making custom sieve/filter for [https://skimagram.com](https://skimagram.com/)(videos and photos) in [Imagus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imagus/immpkjjlgappgfkkfieppnmlhakdmaab?hl=en) hover zoom extension? Relevant [stackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045756/how-to-develop-custom-filters-for-the-imagus-hover-zoom-extension). [Relevant documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sTGh.png) which does not help much.

**FULL EXPLANATION**

I want to browse Instagram videos through tags only. I have found out that skimagram.com can filter [Instagram posts by videos/photos only](https://i.imgur.com/I63xivD.png). Also, clicking on any of the links only takes me to the [original Instagram video/image page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2xUt.jpg).

I have also installed Imagus in Google Chrome so I can just hover and see the video directly instead of clicking and going to another page. However, hovering on it seems to make the [cursor circle in a loop forever](https://i.imgur.com/m4i5aQK.png).

Custom sieve/filter can be added for [any website in Imagus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm02t.png). I searched for documentation regarding Custom sieve but only could find [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sTGh.png). There is another [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045756/how-to-develop-custom-filters-for-the-imagus-hover-zoom-extension) for the same.

I could understand the regEx part but could not understand the javaScript function part since I am not proficient in javaScript.

Can anyone help me in making a custom Imagus sieve for skimagram.com?